# How to achieve the following in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

First of all, Sorry for this lame question. However, I am learning WPF on my own. 
I am learning about `Panel` class now. To learn this I am going through this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx) web-page. The way MSDN has described to create a `Panel` using code appeals me a lot. for instance

```
// Create the application's main window
mainWindow = new Window ();
mainWindow.Title = "Canvas Sample";

// Create the Canvas
myParentCanvas = new Canvas();
myParentCanvas.Width = 400;
myParentCanvas.Height = 400;

// Define child Canvas elements
myCanvas1 = new Canvas();
myCanvas1.Background = Brushes.Red;
Canvas.SetLeft(myCanvas1, 0);
.
.
.
myParentCanvas.Children.Add(myCanvas3);

// Add the parent Canvas as the Content of the Window Object
mainWindow.Content = myParentCanvas;
mainWindow.Show ();
```

I want to create `Panel` (layout) in the way shown on the page, but I am confused where should I write (copy-paste) this code. I am well conversant creating `Layout` using `XAML`

At `filename.xaml.cs` we have got following lines of code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

I tried to put this (MSDN's) lines of code inside `MainWindow` method, but it did not help me much. According to my little knowledge, we should have a method like `mainWindowContent()` and this should be call along `InitializeComponent()` or similar (I might be wrong with this).

Kindly guide me with the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: Show a [mcve] of what you want in XAML and probably a code equivalent can be provided.

Comment: The example in the article shown were most probably done in the start up based on the comments. If you already have a main window you can do everything in the MainWindow constructor after `InitializeComponents`

Comment: SO is not a language let alone _API_ conversion service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Title = "Canvas Sample";

        // Create the Canvas
        var myParentCanvas = new Canvas();
        myParentCanvas.Width = 400;
        myParentCanvas.Height = 400;

        // Define child Canvas elements
        var myCanvas1 = new Canvas();
        myCanvas1.Background = Brushes.Red;
        myCanvas1.Height = 100;
        myCanvas1.Width = 100;
        Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas1, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(myCanvas1, 0);

        var myCanvas2 = new Canvas();
        myCanvas2.Background = Brushes.Green;
        myCanvas2.Height = 100;
        myCanvas2.Width = 100;
        Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas2, 100);
        Canvas.SetLeft(myCanvas2, 100);

        var myCanvas3 = new Canvas();
        myCanvas3.Background = Brushes.Blue;
        myCanvas3.Height = 100;
        myCanvas3.Width = 100;
        Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas3, 50);
        Canvas.SetLeft(myCanvas3, 50);

        // Add child elements to the Canvas' Children collection
        myParentCanvas.Children.Add(myCanvas1);
        myParentCanvas.Children.Add(myCanvas2);
        myParentCanvas.Children.Add(myCanvas3);

        // Add the parent Canvas as the Content of the Window Object
        this.Content = myParentCanvas;
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```xml
<Window Title="Canvas Sample" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Canvas Height="400" Width="400">
    <Canvas Height="100" Width="100" Top="0" Left="0" Background="Red"/>
    <Canvas Height="100" Width="100" Top="100" Left="100" Background="Green"/>
    <Canvas Height="100" Width="100" Top="50" Left="50" Background="Blue"/>
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

If done within the `MainWindow` code-behind itself.

And then on start up you can just call the class

```
// Create the application's main window
var mainWindow = new MainWindow ();
mainWindow.Show ();
```

Comment: thanks for the guidance. Well, I would like to ask a question-" why do you not need to do this (`type objectName = new type()`)? I had to modify this code as `type objName...pe();` Thanks!

Comment: `Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit type var.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx.

Comment: I am aware var keyword and its uses. I wanted to ask it in the context of MSDN sample code. **Should MSDN not try to write as correct code as we all developers have been doing**.